# I have installed python 3.6 but ubuntu still gives python 2.7 when checked for the version. How do I switch to 3.6?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.6

I have successfully installed the latest Python version 3.6 but when checked for the present version of python using "python -V" command it gives Python 2.7 as output. How can I switch to Python 3.6?

Comment: Did you try calling it with `python3`? (to get the version: `python3 -V`

Comment: Try `ls /usr/bin/ | grep '^python'` and check if Python3 is installed.

Comment: Oh Yeah! when tried with python3  -V it gives Python 3.5.2.

Comment: ls /usr/bin/ | grep '^python'
python
python2
python2.7
python2.7-config
python2-config
python3
python3.5
python3.5-config
python3.5m
python3.5m-config
python3.6
python3.6m
python3-config
python3m
python3m-config
python-config

Answer (score 0):

add an alias to .bash_rc and .bash_profile in your home directory after other alias lines near the bottom and the export PATH line respectively as follows:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

This will direct your profile to use python 3.6 in this example everytime you use python and no need to specify python3.  It will not correct the ansible default path however which I am still searching for an answer on how to change that from python2.7 to python3.6.